# Ren windows cmd batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to rename the oldest file in a directory to 'file_oldest'?
I am not sure how to combine date with ren cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. It's a bit trickier for a UNC path.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set share=\\server\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%share%" /b /a-d /o-d') do (set oldest="%%a")
ren "%share%\%oldest%" file_oldest
```

Comment: hi great thanks. where do i state the directory? - replace ('dir /b /a-d /o-d')

Comment: Just add it after the `dir` in the for loop. See edit above. If you only want to perform the rename on a specific file type, you can change `*.*` to `*.<file extension>` like `*.txt` for text files.

Comment: Im getting %%a was unexpected at this time. My directory is a remote share drive. My script i have is for /f %%a in ('dir \\xxxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\*.* /b /a-d /o-d') do set oldest=%%a ren %oldest% file_oldest

Comment: It needs a backslash in the rename command and provision for long filenames/pathname elements.

Comment: Im still getting the '%%a was unexpected at this time.' error after the 3rd line above. I have tested that i can go to the intended dir, there is only 12 file in that dir at present. Im not sure why im getting this error

Comment: Apologies, i think i only get the %%a error above if testing on cmd line, i managed to see the batch file error as it flashed up and it was simply 'the system can not find the path specified. the file name, directory label or volumne label syntax is incorrect'. not sure how as i cut the path out directly and ran it and access it no issue - perhaps i need to eneter my credentials in to the params?

Comment: foxdrive - is your comment still valid after the answer update?

Comment: I don't know. It works fine for me. What do you get if you just type `DIR "\\Server\Share\folder\folder\folder" /b /a-d /o-d` from a `CMD` prompt? It should list all of the files in the directory. The oldest one will be last.

Comment: ok i have it working, however it sets the newest file to the new name
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "\\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\*.*" /b /a-d /od') do (set oldest="%%a")
ren "\\xxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\%oldest%" file_oldest

Comment: That's because you're using `DIR` with /od which means sort by date newest first. You need /o-d so it reverses the order and gets the oldest file. My answer always contained /o-d as well as the comment above, so I'm not sure where it got changed in your code.

Comment: Thats it thanks. It seems a bit messing  -to cycle through the entire folder in the for statement to eventually set the 'oldest' variable to the correct value. It will do for my purposes though, so eternally grateful.